# jsf selectOneMenu strange itemValue

Tags: ajax, jakarta-ee, web-applications, jsf-2, selectonemenu

In my app I have selectOneMenu to select month.

```
                    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{register.monthOfBirth}">
                        <f:selectItems value="#{register.dateValues.monthsList}" var="month" itemLabel="#{month.valueLabel}" itemValue="#{month.valueValue}"/>
                        <f:ajax listener="#{register.monthChanged}" render="messages" />
                    </h:selectOneMenu>
```

Here's my DateValues class which I use to populate selectOneMenu's:

```
    public class DateValues {

    public static class Values{
    public String valueLabel;
    public String valueValue;

    public Values(String valueLabel, String valueValue){
        this.valueLabel = valueValue;
        this.valueLabel = valueValue;
    }

    public String getValueLabel(){
        return valueLabel;
    }

    public String getValueValue(){
        return valueValue;
    }

}

    public Values[] daysList;
    public Values[] monthsList;
    public Values[] yearsList;

    public DateValues(){
            daysList = new Values[31];
            for(int i=0;i<31;i++){
                daysList[i] = new Values(""+ (i+1),""+(i+1));
            }
            monthsList = new Values[12];
            for(int i=0;i<12;i++){
                monthsList[i] = new Values("" + (i+1),"" + (i+1));
            }
            yearsList = new Values[109];
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            int currentYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int first = currentYear - 108;
            for(int i=0;i<109;i++) {
                yearsList[i] = new Values("" + (first + (108-i)),"" + (first + (108-i)));
            }
    }



public Values[] getDaysList() {
    return daysList;
}


    public Values[] getMonthsList() {
    return monthsList;

}

    public Values[] getYearsList() {
    return yearsList;
}

    }
```

In the @ManagedBean I've got an ajax listener:

```
        public void monthChanged(){
           System.out.println("New month is month number " + monthOfBirth);

        }
```

What I get in the output is:

```
    "INFO: New month is month number dyplom.dyplom.date.DateValues$Values@79f6099"
```

instead of (for example) 2 (number of month, so February)

What did I do wrong?

EDIT:

GENERATED HTML:

```
    <h2><select id="j_idt56:j_idt70" name="j_idt56:j_idt70" size="1" onchange="mojarra.ab(this,event,'valueChange',0,'j_idt56:messages')">  <option value="dyplom.dyplom.date.DateValues$Values@32b0c37e">1</option>
       <option value="dyplom.dyplom.date.DateValues$Values@72f29f31">2</option>
       <option value="dyplom.dyplom.date.DateValues$Values@16b184ec">3</option>
       <option value="dyplom.dyplom.date.DateValues$Values@608dad97">4</option>
       <option value="dyplom.dyplom.date.DateValues$Values@757fc606">5</option>
       <option value="dyplom.dyplom.date.DateValues$Values@17a1f02e">6</option>
       <option value="dyplom.dyplom.date.DateValues$Values@89f6821">7</option>
       <option value="dyplom.dyplom.date.DateValues$Values@196d52f3">8</option>
       <option value="dyplom.dyplom.date.DateValues$Values@5860dc8f">9</option>
       <option value="dyplom.dyplom.date.DateValues$Values@3f305d9d">10</option>
       <option value="dyplom.dyplom.date.DateValues$Values@520ed4">11</option>
       <option value="dyplom.dyplom.date.DateValues$Values@b4b8076">12</option>
   </select>
   </h2>
```

Comment: Can you show whole code? Where is variable called `monthOfBirth`? Your `itemValue` is of type `String`, so `monthOfBirth` should be `String`.

Comment: Does `Values` properly implemement `toString()`. Because the issue here is that you are trying to print an object as String, and if you have not overriden `toString()` you get the default result (which is what is showing).

Comment: @SJuan76
Do I have to only override toString() in 'Values' ? Or am I supposed to implement a converter? I was hoping that when 'itemValue' and 'value' of selectOneMenu are both the same type (String) there is no need for any additional actions.

Comment: Are you sure `{register.monthOfBirth}` is a String? I had assumed it was a `Values`; if it is a String I would expect it to work ok. In that case, could you check the generated HTML to find which values are used there?

Comment: Are you sure you're running the code you think you're running? Rebuild/redeploy/restart to be sure.

Comment: @BalusC 
Yes I am totally sure I'm running the right code and I rebuilded/redeployed/restarted dozen times.

Comment: @SJuan76  Yes I'm sure that `register.monthOfBirth` is a String.  
I've joined the generated HTML u asked for to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved!
I'm so ashamed of the mistake I made!
Take a look at the constructor of `Values`:

```
public Values(String valueLabel, String valueValue){
    this.valueLabel = valueValue;
    this.valueLabel = valueValue;
}
```

As you can see I've been setting up twice valueLabel with wrong variable and moreover I didn't set valueValue at all!

Now as I corrected constructor:

```
public Values(String valueLabel, String valueValue){
    this.valueLabel = valueLabel;
    this.valueValue = valueValue;
}
```

everything is alright :)
Sorry for the mess!